# Проверка типов в конструкторе с std::forward

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++, конструктор

```
class A
{
public:
    using number_t = std::int32_t;
    using string_t = std::string;

    template < class T >
    using vector_t = std::vector < T >;

public:
    template < class T1, class T2, class T3 >
    A(T1 && n, T2 && s, T3 && v) :
        m_n { std::forward < T1 > (n) },
        m_s { std::forward < T2 > (s) },
        m_v { std::forward < T3 > (v) } {}

private:
    number_t              m_n;
    string_t              m_s;
    vector_t < number_t > m_v;
};
```

**Вопрос**: нужно ли проверять типы `T1`, `T2`, `T3` в конструкторе? Я так полагаю, что нужно, потому что этот конструктор запросто съедает, например, в качестве первого аргумента `double`, что нежелательно. Как корректно сделать проверку? Рассматриваю вариант `std::enable_if_t` и `std::is_same`. Если так, то как удалять ссылки в случае приема конструктором lvalue-значения? Компилятор ругается на `std::is_same < number_t, std::remove_reference< T1 >::type >::value`. Пишет: «ожидался тип, а не вот это».

Comment: Простите, если нужны **конкретные типы**, то зачем у вас вообще шаблон? Кой в нем смысл, если он должен работать только если T1 - int32_t и не иначе?...

Comment: @Harry, а rvalue-lvalue?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward - вот отсюда переделанный пример.

Comment: Так а перегрузка обычная зачем?

Comment: @Harry так а при n параметрах мы вроде как 2^n рост количества перегруженных вариантов получаем?

Comment: Ото-то так... но что-то мне кажется, что в реальной жизни все будет проще :) А по сути - может, `std::decay` попробовать?

Comment: @Harry И можно свернуть, обрыв обогнуть, но мы выбираем трудный путь, опасный, как военная тропа... :) decay сейчас попробую. А в чем таки проблема с remove_reference?

Comment: Может, какая очепятка?

Comment: @Harry https://ideone.com/rSBdd1 вроде опечаток нет. Да и описание ошибки намекает что тип из основного шаблона не проходит в remove_reference. Что-то где-то не выводится.

Comment: возможно связанные вопросы на enSO, которые вроде объясняют, почему не стоит так делать: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16724657/5812238, https://stackoverflow.com/q/39645986/5812238

Comment: Мля, ну я уже совсем того, видно, пора на пенсию... В вашем коде просмотрел очевидное - развратил меня VC++ 2017 :) **typename**!!! вот что пропущено - см. https://ideone.com/tu4vNg

Comment: @Harry верно, спасибо! У меня тот же синдром, видимо( Я вот сейчас задумался - у нас с rvalue все хорошо в таком к-ре, а вот если передаем lvalue, то как дать гарантии (кроме аккуратного написания тела к-ра), что этот lvalue по ссылке не изменится? Ведь писать const нехорошо, будет тогда const SomeType&& и прощай перемещение... Хотя в чужих примерах я видел именно так, как на ideone мы писали.

Comment: Пока что сам не знаю... С этой универсальностью всегда больше вопросов, чем ответов :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, что в данном случае логично применить `std::decay` - типа

```
template<class T1, class T2, class T3,
    typename = enable_if_t<is_same_v<decay_t<T1>,int>>,
    typename = enable_if_t<is_same_v<decay_t<T2>,int>>,
    typename = enable_if_t<is_same_v<decay_t<T3>,int>>
    >
B(T1&& t1, T2&& t2, T3&& t3) :
    a1_{std::forward<T1>(t1)},
    a2_{std::forward<T2>(t2)},
    a3_{std::forward<T3>(t3)}
{
}
```

Кстати говоря,

```
typename = enable_if_t<is_same_v<int,remove_reference_t<T1>>>
```

тоже вполне работает. Причем в определенных ситуациях даже лучше - например, `const int` `decay` пропустит, убрав `const`, а вот `remove_reference_t` - уже нет, так что если, например, конструктор требует именно ссылку, а не константную ссылку - лучше `remove_reference_t`, если константную ссылку - лучше `decay`.

Словом, подгонять по месту с помощью напильника и какой-то матери... :)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант решения - можно использовать `std::is_convertible` вместо `std::is_same`:

```
using number_type = std::uint64_t;
using string_type = std::string;
using vector_type = std::vector < int >;

template < typename S, typename V,
           typename Enable = std::enable_if_t < 
    std::is_convertible < std::decay_t < S > *, string_type * > ::value && 
    std::is_convertible < std::decay_t < V > *, vector_type * > ::value > >
Implementation(number_type number, S && string, V && vector) noexcept(true) :
    m_number { std::move (number) },
    m_string { std::forward < S > (string) },
    m_vector { std::forward < V > (vector) }
{}
```